# Converting exponential to integer in python

Tags: python, floating-point, int, exponential

When I execute this python code:

```
integer = 18243150071292141317265306851
print(int(integer / 1))
```

The output I receive is: `18243150071292140668971909120` which does not equal to  `integer`.

Why does this happen and how can I make the output equal to `integer`?

Comment: what is `checkInt`?

Comment: `/` always does float division (in Python 3). If you want integer division, use the floor division operator `//`.

Comment: `int(some_expression)` _doesn't_ say "use integer arithmetic to evaluate `some_expression`". `int()` is the integer constructor, and if you pass it some expression, it will evaluate that expression, and then try to construct an integer from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That result can be achieved in Python3 (or Python2 with true division imported from `future`), but not Python2 in stock mode.

The operator `/` always generate "true" quotient (with fractional part), but first it converts both arguments to its `float` (which is the same as `double` in C). And this conversion is where precision is lost because this `float` has only 53 significant binary digits (guessing your platform is `IEEE754` based, as >99% are). The argument divided by 1 is already rounded in that way and gets equal to 18243150071292140668971909120.

(It seems Python language documentation is not precise here in operatorʼs effects. It [notes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) that "The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type" but forgets that, to get a `float` result, the simplest way is utilized - to rely on platformʼs floating division.)

Then, conversion back to `int` (that is exact and essentially unlimited) gives the same value and you see it printed.

To get what you expect, use `//` instead of `/`: the "floor division" (`//`) doesn't convert its arguments to `float`. (OTOH, if some of them is already `float`, it can convert another one to perform floating division and them truncate result to flooring integer value.)

This is essentially the same you are told by @PM2Ring but formed as answer.

If you want to make calculations with not-only-integer numbers with precision more than a usual `float` provides, you should get out of intrinsic types and consider using `decimal` from the standard library, `GMP` library [wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy/) or a similar solution.